# All drinks can be drunk or drank

Tags: verbs, tenses

I tried doing some research,  but couldn't find the answer to my question. My question is simple. In the following sentence; "Everything can be drunk", should I use drank instead of drunk? As this is stating a possibility, I know that there might be special grammar rules applied to this, which is why the links I found are not good enough.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: "Drunk" would be better

Comment: Very easy: irregular verbs: drink, drank, drunk; may be drunk. May be seen [see, saw, seen], etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Drunk](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can%20be%20drank%2Ccan%20be%20drunk&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20be%20drank%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20be%20drunk%3B%2Cc0)***  is the more common and standard form used as past participle of  *"to drink"*:

> - To drink something is to swallow a liquid. The past tense of drink is either drank or drunk, though the latter is used twice as often as the former.
> - ***A past participle is the adjective or adverb form of a verb.*** In this case, [drunk](http://grammarist.com/usage/drink-drank-drunk/) is used exclusively with the verb have. ***Some will say that drank is not the past participle. However, it is listed in some dictionaries and used widely as such.*** If you are concerned about your audience, stick with have drunk and I drank.

(The Grammarist)

[Usage note:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/drank?s=t)

> - As with many verbs of the pattern sing, sang, sung and ring, rang, rung, there is some confusion about the forms for the past tense and past participle of drink. ***The historical reason for this confusion is that originally verbs of this class in Old English had a past-tense singular form in a but a past-tense plural form in u.***
> - Generally the form in a has leveled out to become the standard past-tense form: We drank our coffee.However, the past-tense form in u, though considered nonstandard, occurs often in speech: We drunk our coffee. 
>     ***The standard and most frequent form of the past participle of drink in both speech and writing is drunk*** : Who has drunk all the milk?However, perhaps because of the association of drunk with intoxication, ***drank is widely used as a past participle in speech by educated persons and must be considered an alternate standard form: The tourists had drank their fill of the scenery.***

(Dictionary.com)